# How to autocomplete dynamically created objects in python code?

Tags: python, lsp-mode, autocompletion

Is anybody able to get suggestions after typing `x.` using code below? E.g. `name`

```python
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace


data = '{"name": "John Smith", "hometown": {"name": "New York", "id": 123}}'

# Parse JSON into an object with attributes corresponding to dict keys.
x = json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
print(x.name, x.hometown.name, x.hometown.id)
```

The upper example stems from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15882054/1172907)

Another promising approach is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773539/how-do-i-convert-a-json-file-to-a-python-class), yet no auto-completion as well

I'm using lsp-pyright

Answer (score 0):

Auto-completion, in this case, is not something you're going to get from static parsers. As far as they're concerned `data` is just a string, and `json.loads()` returns an "object". The "making the string of JSON data named 'data' into a python object and assigning it to 'x'" part requires executing `json.loads()` which static parsers don't do because that would be "dynamic", à la what happens when input your sample code into the `python`/`ipython` REPL. After hitting `Return` on your `x = json.loads(...)` the python REPL runs `json.loads()` on the string `data`, creates the python object, and assigns it to `x`. This is why at the next and future statements you can autocomplete on `x.<tab>` there. If your example `data` statement was a python dict, and your `x = json.loads(...)` was maybe a `x = map(..)`, then yes you would get autocompletion on your `print()` line.

tl;dr

What you're asking for is outside the job of static parsers, which are typically the backend of your "lsp server", therefore they don't understand the input and can't accommodate your expectations.

Comment: maybe somewhere out there is an `ipython` lsp backend that would suit your needs in this case. though i think there might be a huge speed/convenience trade off.